# Error while uploading file in grails 2.3.7

Tags: java, spring, grails

I am going to attach a file when send the email.

```
<g:formRemote id="emailWidgetForm" name="emailOrderMailForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"
 on404="alert('not found!')"
 onLoading="showSpinner('emailWidget');" onComplete="hideSpinner();"
 url="[controller: 'emailSender', action:'sendPersonalEmailToCustomer']"
 action="${createLink(controller: 'emailOrder', action:  
 'sendPersonalEmailToCustomer')}"
 before="if( validateGivenForm( 'emailWidgetForm' ) ) { " after="}">

 <tr>
 <td><strong>Attachment</strong></td>
 <td><input type="file" size="10" name="attachments"/></td>
 </tr>
 <g:submitButton name="sendEmailButton" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                    value="Send  Email"/>
 </g:formRemote>
```

When I am going to get this in controler like

```
def file = request.getFile('attachments');
```

I am getting Error on this above line.

The error is

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:   
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [attachments]
Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getJSON()
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[**Edit** - disregard this as per Burt's comment. It would only work in Java/Spring]

You might have to cast your `request` object to the usual `MultipartHttpServletRequest`:

```
MultipartHttpServletRequest mhsr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request
MultipartFile file = mhsr.getFile("attachments")
```

As Spring security appears to be injecting its own `Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` version of `request`, I'm guessing.

Comment: This is Groovy - casting never helps to get access to a property or method (except when using `@CompileStatic` which requires lots of casts like Java) since it is resolved not by the type you claiming it to be when compiling, but by what it actually is at runtime. In any servlet API app the 'real' container-created Request will be proxied multiple times, with the extras that Grails and Spring add, and one or two added by the spring-security-core plugin, there are lots of layers there (around 7 iirc)

Answer (score 0):

There are are [Jira](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8576) issues for that, Just set `grails.web.disable.multipart=true` in Config file